# all my android projects have phantom errors

Tags: android

Any of the projects that I have open have errors all of a sudden. Ive tried reinstalling java, eclipse, and android but nothing works. However, when I import the projects to my other computer they have no errors. Am I going to have to format my machine? I just went through every process but that and I really dont want to take a day just to reformat and reinstall all the software that I need.....But I will.

The errors are at the projects root file at the top of the tree but there are no errors anywhere in the whole project.....so freakin weird

Comment: You should open the problems view and tell us what errors you can see.

Comment: You might be able to see what the problem is by looking at the `Problems` view (`Window > Show View > Problems`). Edit: *Snicolas beat me to it :)*

Comment: I wasnt sure what kind of errors until I finally found something.The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 - The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 - The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments                                                                          These errors were listed in the top of one of my .java files but there were no actual instances of any such error through out that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem a few weeks.  Look in the Problems folder of eclipse.  See if you debug certifcate expired.  Reference: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/eclipse-throws-debug-certificate-expired/  This page gives you directions to fix.

Comment: That was it man thank you :) all my projects are back to normal. However now Im having a problem with my latest project. It left an error in there that I mentioned up above

Comment: I fixed that too. I just erased the project from eclipse and remade it as a new project....yay for me :p

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting.. may be .. extreme. If these phantom errors happen only in eclipse, then uninstall it, look up on the next where eclipse stores its preferences (I used to remember this but forgot) delete those folder. Now install eclipse again, preferably in a different folder structure. Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Ahhhh.....I didnt bother to look for the preferences folder :p thanks....if I cant get it to work first Ill just eradicate every trace of eclipse I can and start completely over :)

Answer (score 1):

I updated the android ADT using Help>Installed New Software in eclipse. It got rid of the errors and it updated my AVD Manager